How to add Gap / Space in SubMenu
I'm not at all familiar with editing code and have had a hard time building this WordPress site (https://danielpainter.at) for myself (feel free to join the site).
How is it possible to create a distance (gap/spacae) between the buttons in the sub-menu?
Now: now
Should be: should be
The affected code should be
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-3259" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3259"><a href="https://www.danielpainter.at/personen/?customize_changeset_uuid=a01ae230-11ac-4842-b96d-97f9812df568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on"><span>Personen</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4657" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4657"><a href="https://www.danielpainter.at/urbex/?customize_changeset_uuid=a01ae230-11ac-4842-b96d-97f9812df568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on"><span>Urbex</span></a></li>
</ul>

the css
.navigation .sub-menu, .navigation .children {
    top: 100%;
}
.navigation .sub-menu, .navigation .children {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 200px;
    left: 0;
    top: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #464646;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 5;
}

I'm not at all familiar with editing code

You are expected to provide a proper [mre] of the issue within the question, not just snippets that lack context. Just a link to the live site is not enough, see also Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

Currently, the ul.sub-menu has a border on all sides, and the li except the last one have a border-bottom. So you will need to remove the border from the ul, and make all the li have a border on all sides - and then you can introduce a gap between the li, for example by giving them some margin.

After a long search, I was able to find the following


.navigation .sub-menu,
.navigation .children {
  border: none;
}

.navigation .sub-menu li,
.navigation .children li {
  margin-top:8px;
  padding-top: 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #464646;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #464646;
}

.navigation .sub-menu li:last-of-type,
.navigation .children li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #464646;
}






<ul style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; gap: 10px;">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>



You should define flex for your list than define the direction which is column for your example. Than You should define "gap" prop as above.
Also how you do it with css:


ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px; /* Adjust the gap as needed */
}



